# Initialize variable inside if statement (Java)

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I'm assigning my variables in an `if` statement and trying to use them outside of it, but I can't figure out how. The error is in the very last `if` statement stating that "local variable may not have been initialized".

```
int i,z;
if (st1.nextToken() == "Ace")
{
    String Ace = "14";
    i = Integer.parseInt(Ace);  
}
else if (st2.nextToken() == "Ace")
{
    String Ace = "14";
    z = Integer.parseInt(Ace);
}
else if (st1.nextToken() == "King")
{
    String King = "13";
    i = Integer.parseInt(King); 
}
else if (st2.nextToken() == "King")
{
    String King = "13";
    z = Integer.parseInt(King); 
}
else if (st1.nextToken() == "Queen")
{
    String Queen= "12";
    i = Integer.parseInt(Queen);
}
else if (st2.nextToken() == "Queen")
{
    String Queen= "12";
    z = Integer.parseInt(Queen);
}
else if (st1.nextToken() == "Jack")
{
    String Jack = "11";
    i = Integer.parseInt(Jack);
}
else if (st2.nextToken() == "Jack")
{
    String Jack = "11";
    z = Integer.parseInt(Jack); 
    break;
}
else
{
    i = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());  
    z = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
}
if (i > z)
```

Comment: Which variable need initialized

Comment: What happens if first if condition (=="ACE") doesn't satisfy? local variable should have initiated in all possible execution paths before you use it. One solution just add else for first if and initiate i,z. I see another problem in your code, Java string comparison uses equals() NOT ==

Comment: You need to have both `i` and `z` initialized in every path. Most of your conditional statements only initialize one of them. Also consider reformatting the code, since at first glance it looks like you are using nested conditionals.

Comment: Again in java, I believe you should use the .equals method for String comparison...not == operator....except you REALLY know what you are doing. as in       if(st1.nextToken().equals("Ace"))

Comment: @Nambari and @gbenroscience are correct, you should be using `st1.nextToken().equals("Ace")` (and so on) for string comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
int i,z;
```

with:

```
int i=0, z=0;  //or whatever value you want
```

Or initialize both `i` and `z` to some value in all of your `if-else` blocks.

You cannot do `if(i>z)` unless both are initialized because you need to initialize local variables.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must be satisfied that both `i` and `z` have been initialised before it will permit the comparison `i > z`. Your code does not guarantee this as only some paths through your `if..else` logic will initialise both variables.

You have a couple of options:

- Initiliase `i` and `z` at the very beginning, eg. to 0 or some other suitable default
- Make sure you set `i` and `z` in every `if` block

A couple of other style issues:

- Use `equals()` to compare strings, not `==`, eg. `st1.nextToken().equals("Ace")`
- Assigning a string value (containing a number) to a string and then parsing it for the integer is inefficient. You can simple assign an integer value.

Thus:

```
String Jack = "11";
i = Integer.parseInt(Jack);
```

can become:

```
i = 11;
```

or:

```
i = JACK;   // where JACK is a constant set to 11
```

You may also have a bug with respect to the tokens being read. Each `if` expression calls [nextToken()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken()) which will cause the *next* token in the stream to be used. I imagine you want to compare the *current* token in each expression. If this is the case, then assign to two temporary variables to hold the next tokens for `st1` and `st2` before your `if..else` logic and compare these to Ace, King, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution for String compares, in this case, would be to use a switch/case statement

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class. If none of the conditions before last if statement satisfy, put a check if those *Integers* are initialized with `null` check.